# How to change MUI DatePicker Calendar selected date background color using makeStyles

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I want to change the background colour of selected date in MUI datePicker.  As shown in below picture i need to change the blue color to some other color.
Below is my code

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  datePickerStyle: {
    "& .css-bkrceb-MuiButtonBase-root-MuiPickersDay-root.Mui-selected": {
    backgroundColor: "red",
    color: '#000000'
  },
  }
```

```
        <DatePicker
          disablePast
          value={checkout.rideDate}
          shouldDisableDate={getDisabledDates}
          onChange={(newValue) => {
            dispatch(setRideDate(newValue?.toISOString().split('T')[0]))
          }}
          renderInput={(params) => <TextField className={classes.datePickerStyle} {...params} 
          />
          }
```

[image]

Comment: are you using mui v4 or v5?

Comment: I am using these versions package  "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3"  ,  "@mui/styles": "^5.3.0",

Answer (score 7):

I resolved it by passing style in PaperProps like this:

```
            PaperProps={{
              sx: {
                "& .MuiPickersDay-root": {
                  "&.Mui-selected": {
                    backgroundColor: colors.Cerulean,
                  },
                },
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8DWw.png